# Como eliminar palabras prohibidas que pueden o no estar rodeadas por corchetes

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito eliminar las palabras prohibidas de un texto, y también eliminar brackets (corchetes) si los tuviesen antes o después.

Este es el código que intenté:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  
  var palabrasProhibidas = ['mala','[mala]'];
        var numeroPalabrasProhibidas = palabrasProhibidas.length;
        
        var text = "[mala]";

            
        while(numeroPalabrasProhibidas--) {
           if (text.indexOf(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas])!=-1) {
               text = text.replace(new RegExp(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas], 'ig'), ""); // SIN PALABRAS PROHIBIDAS
           }
        }
         var b = text.indexOf("[");
        var c = text.indexOf("]");
         var textc = text.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, "");  // SIN CORCHETES

        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText("sin [ ]: " + textc,5,50);
        ctx.fillText("sin prohibida: " + text,5,100);
        
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>UNK</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Uno me entrega el string sin corchetes y otro sin las palabras prohibidas, con esto mis problemas son:

1. Necesito hacer ambas juntas. O sea, quitar los brackets y a la vez las palabras prohibidas.
2. No puedo cambiar la variable `text`. O sea que al final debo además también dibujar la palabra original sin ningún cambio (quitar los brackets y las palabras prohibidas sin cambiar la  variable original).

Comment: No es muy claro lo que pretendes hacer en el programa. ¿Buscas obtener tus palabras prohibidas sin corchetes y a la vez sin la palabra prohibida (puros corchetes)? ¿Para qué ocupas RegExp en tu `while` y para qué es ese ciclo?

Comment: @Eduardo Para que tu pregunta sea más clara, por favor, ¿podrías incluir la información que se pide en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info? Sería bueno que en todas las preguntas de expresiones regulares incluyas: diferentes ejemplos de texto contra el cual debería coincidir, el resultado esperado, y casos en los cuales no debería coincidir.

Answer (score 4):

Se puede resumir en una única expresión regular:

```
/\[?(?:mala|palabra2|palabra3|etc)\]?/gi
```

- `\[?` - corchetes [opcionales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark).
- `(?:mala|palabra2|palabra3|etc)` - un [grupo sin captura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) que coincide con cualquiera de las palabras listadas, separadas por [`|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or) ([alternancia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or)).
- `\]?` - corchetes [opcionales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark).
- Modificadores: `g` (reemplazar todas las coincidencias), `i` (ignorar mayúsculas/minúsculas).

Además, quizás te interese que las palabras coincidan sólo si son *palabras completas*. Por ejemplo, para que no se eliminen de `"comala"`, ni `"malaria"`. Para eso utilizamos el [límite de palabra](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) [`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary).

```
/\[?\b(?:mala|palabra2|palabra3|etc)\b\]?/gi
```

---

#### Código

```js
var regex = /\[?\b(?:mala|palabra2|palabra3|etc)\b\]?/gi,
    texto = 'Elimina [mala] o mala de una frase, pero no de [mala], ni por mala, dejando malaria',
    resultado;
    
//Reemplazar
resultado = texto.replace(regex, '');

//Mostrar el resultado
console.log(resultado); // => Elimina  o  de una frase, pero no de , ni por , dejando malaria
```

---

#### Generar el regex de palabras prohibidas dinámicamente.

Si además quisieras generar la expresión desde un array dinámicamente, deberías unirlo con `"|"`, pero considerando que hay que escapar los caracteres especiales. Para eso, declaramos la función `escaparRegex()` que le antecede una `\` a cualquier metacaracter.

```js
var texto = 'Elimina [mala] o mala de una frase, pero no de [mala], ni por mala, dejando malaria',
    resultado;


//Listado de palabras prohibidas
var prohibidas = ["mala", "pa^la^bra^2", "etc"];

//Generar el regex
function escaparRegex(string) {
    return string.replace(/[\\^$.|?*+()[{]/g, '\\$&'); 
}

var prohibidasOr = prohibidas.map(escaparRegex).join('|'),
    regex = new RegExp('\\[?\\b(?:' + prohibidasOr + ')\\b\\]?', 'gi');


//Reemplazar
resultado = texto.replace(regex, '');

//Mostrar el resultado
console.log(resultado); // => Elimina  o  de una frase, pero no de , ni por , dejando malaria
```

Comment: Enterado. Borrado mi comentario previo.